# Spring Boot Test emmbedded MongoDB: Combine MockMVC with @DataMongoTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, junit5

In my Spring boot 2.2.1 project I'm trying to test output from endpoint call.
It's agreed to use embedded MongoDB for tests.
However we couldn't use `MockMvc` and `@DataMongoTest` in the same test class.

```
@DataMongoTest
@WebMvcTest
public class FacesCRUDTest {
  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  //test methods that use mockMvc
...
```

I've tried almost 100 combinations of @AutoConfigue.. annotations.

For the above given code I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.exadel.frs.core.trainservice.repository.FacesCRUDTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.DataMongoTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper)]

    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:166)
    at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:88)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:77)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:355)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:77)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:132)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.exadel.frs.core.trainservice.repository.FacesCRUDTest]: [@org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.DataMongoTestContextBootstrapper), @org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapWith(value=org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper)]
        at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveExplicitTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:166)
        at org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils.resolveTestContextBootstrapper(BootstrapUtils.java:127)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:122)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:81)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:182)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.remove(ExtensionValuesStore.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.remove(NamespaceAwareStore.java:73)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:89)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:421)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$14(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:421)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:421)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:213)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:77)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        ... 27 more
```

Please help me to find a way to test API using embedded MongoDB.

Here is a snippet from pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I solved this in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313608/mockmvc-not-injected-when-datamongotest-used/66315228  If you havent already.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. To resolve this, i just merge both annotation (by copying and adjust files, see bellow), it's not really satisfying but it solve the problem for the moment, and the test looks like i want.

Here is a copy of WebMvcTest interface (with little adjustment in annotations to include mongo)

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@AutoConfigureWebMvc
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
@TypeExcludeFilters({WebMvcTypeExcludeFilter.class, DataMongoTypeExcludeFilter.class})
@BootstrapWith(WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@AutoConfigureCache
@ImportAutoConfiguration
public @interface DataMongoWebMvcTest {...copy from WebMvcTest
```

Then I add DataMongoTypeExcludeFilter and WebMvcTypeExcludeFilter changing anotation name see bellow fields to change, and I add WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper (no change).

```
private final DataMongoWebMvcTest annotation;

WebMvcTypeExcludeFilter(Class<?> testClass) {
    this.annotation = AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotation(testClass,
            DataMongoWebMvcTest.class);
}
```

And here is a test class example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import({ObjectController.class, ObjectService.class})
@DataMongoWebMvcTest(secure = false)
public class ObjectControllerIntTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private CustomRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/endpoint")
                .content(content)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        ExpectedObject expectedObject = new Object();

        List<SavedObject> savedObject = repository.findAll();
        assertEquals(content, savedObject.get(0));
    }

}
```

Hope this help.