# MockMvc not injected when @DataMongoTest used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have a Spring Integration test configured in the following way with an embedded Mongo DB Database:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TpimApplication.class)
//@SpringBootTest(classes=SPApplication.class)
//@WebMvcTest(controllers = {ControllerA.class, ControllerB.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@DataMongoTest
public class IntegrationUnitTests {

    private static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://%s:%d";

    private static MongodExecutable mongodExecutable;
    private static MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
//    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() throws Exception {
        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 65535;

        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .net(new Net(ip, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .build();

        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
        mongodExecutable.start();
        mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(String.format(CONNECTION_STRING, ip, port)), "TestDB");
        
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("mocked_data/test_data.json");
        setupData(resource, "test_collection");

    }

@Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/endpoint")
                .header("header1", "api-key")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        
        this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Whenever I run my tests I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tests.IntegrationUnitTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mockMvc'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:392)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:362)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    ... 69 more
```

**What is causing the `mockMvc` not to be injected here ?**

I even have `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` present.

What is going wrong ?

EDIT:

My Dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--   -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-starter-azure-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <!--<version>4.3.1</version> -->
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
 -->        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-logging-logback</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: As well, kindly paste your dependencies

Answer (score 2):

ok I got it working using the below code.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
@SpringBootTest
public class FirstControllerIT {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private FirstController controller;
    
    
    

}
```

Looks like you are not able to use @SpringbootTest and @DataMongoTest at the same time.  And for @AutoConfigureMockMVC, it needs the spring context.

You can still setup mockMVC using standalone(Without @Autowired/Spring context) using the below code if you dont want to use @SpringBootTest.

```
 mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
```

================================ Edited: To showcase the use of Embedded DB ==

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
@SpringBootTest
public class FirstControllerIT {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    private FirstController controller;
    
    private static final String CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://%s:%d";
    
    
    private MongodExecutable mongodExecutable;
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @AfterEach
    void clean() {
        mongodExecutable.stop();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() throws Exception {
        String ip = "localhost";
        int port = 27017;

        IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .net(new Net(ip, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .build();

        MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
        mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);
        mongodExecutable.start();
        mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(String.format(CONNECTION_STRING, ip, port)), "test");
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        // given
        DBObject objectToSave = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("key", "value")
            .get();

        // when
        mongoTemplate.save(objectToSave, "collection");

    }

}
```

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-embedded-mongodb

================ Final Edit ================

If you have embeddedMongodb in your dependencies, then Spring will autowire everything, that includes your mongotemplate in your Repositories.

Dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.AutoConfigureDataMongo;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import com.example.demo.repository.Entity;
import com.example.demo.repository.FirstMongoRepository;


@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
@SpringBootTest
public class FirstControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private FirstMongoRepository repository;


    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        
        Entity firstEntity = new Entity("Susan");
        
        System.out.println(repository.save(firstEntity));
        System.out.println(repository.count());

    }

}
```

Repository

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface FirstMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Entity, String> {
        
    
}
```

Entity

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Entity {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String name;
    
    public Entity() {}

    public Entity(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "Entity with name " + name;
    }
}
```

Log:

```
2021-02-22 14:54:01.487  INFO 30056 --- [localhost:57976] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:1}] to localhost:57976
2021-02-22 14:54:01.487  INFO 30056 --- [localhost:57976] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:2}] to localhost:57976
2021-02-22 14:54:01.487  INFO 30056 --- [localhost:57976] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:57976, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=null, roundTripTimeNanos=28842700}
2021-02-22 14:54:01.864  INFO 30056 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2021-02-22 14:54:01.864  INFO 30056 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2021-02-22 14:54:01.866  INFO 30056 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-02-22 14:54:01.886  INFO 30056 --- [           main] c.e.demo.controller.FirstControllerIT    : Started FirstControllerIT in 4.803 seconds (JVM running for 5.942)
2021-02-22 14:54:02.161  INFO 30056 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-02-22T14:54:02.161+0100 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:57979 #3 (3 connections now open)
2021-02-22 14:54:02.161  INFO 30056 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.b.a.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongo     : 2021-02-22T14:54:02.162+0100 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:57979 conn3: { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver|sync|spring-boot", version: "4.1.1" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Windows 10", architecture: "amd64", version: "10.0" }, platform: "Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_201-b09" }
2021-02-22 14:54:02.163  INFO 30056 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:3, serverValue:3}] to localhost:57976
Entity with name Susan
1
2021-02-22 14:54:02.257  INFO 30056 --- [extShutdownHook] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection
```

Springboot will autowire and initiate an embedded mongodb cluster (However in my example, I am not changing the port, nor the database name).  I leave that to you.

This should solve your initial problem of having both an embeddedMongoDb + working mockMVC.

Comment: No, this is trying to connect to my **real** MongoDB cluster. It is not connecting to the embedded one. I am getting `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information`. I have shutdown my MongoDB instance to verify if it is connecting to the embedded one.

Comment: I have also tried to a standalone setup but the service beans are not getting injected into the controller.

Comment: Try shutting of your mongoDB instance and running the code.

Comment: @ng.newbie It is working with embedded mongodb now.

Comment: This is only if you save from the mongoTemplate. Try saving from your repository you will see you are hitting your original database.

Comment: Meaning your repositories will not use the `mongoTemplate` that points to the embedded DB. Try it out if you don't believe me. Make sure to keep your Mongo Server off during the testing.

Comment: @ng.newbie I dont have any mongodb running locally......